# How do I wire my old 3/4hp 115-120v 50-60Hz HVAC motor to make an exhaust fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, blower

My old HVAC blower motor has the following wires and I would like to know how to wire them to a typical 110v plug for use as a garage exhaust fan.
yellow (N)
black (L)
yellow/green (ground)
black (M1)
blue (M2)
orange (M3)
white (M4)
gray (M5)
brown (com)
There wasn't a capacitor on the furnace blower motor assy, but there was a 24vac transformer.  Any help with this project is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure of this project? Do you really need a 3/4HP motor for an exhaust blower? Have you found a safe way to cage the thing you are proposing to build?

Comment: How was it wired up in the application you removed it from?

Comment: Either that thing is more than a motor, or that label is off of something that's more than a motor.

Comment: It's a blower motor/fan assembly out of a residential York furnace that is only about two years old.

Comment: It was originally wired to a circuit board controlling the furnace.

Comment: What was the model number of the furnace?

Comment: Sounds like an electronically commutated motor (ECM).  Check the furnace board, it should have had a controller on it. If Brown is common, Black, Blue, Orange, White, and Gray would have been used to signal the motor.

Answer (score 1):

As it sounds like it's an electronically commutated motor (ECM).  My advice is to grab the control board, blower, and transformer out of the furnace. Then connect everything up as it was in the furnace.  You should then be able to use the `R` and `G` thermostat terminals, to turn the fan on and off.

You will have to bypass any limit circuits on the board, but it shouldn't matter since you're only using the blower.